# Show that $\hom_R(f, M)$ is a quasi-isomorphism if $f:P \to P'$ is a quasi-isomorphism of $K$-projectives complexes

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

*For any complexes of $R$-modules, $P$ and $M$, $\hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(P,M)$ is the complexe defined by,*
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}\ \ \ \hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(P,M)_n = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \hom_R(P_i, M_{i+n})$$

*We say that a complexe $P$ is $\pi$-projective or K-projective, if for all quasi-isomorphisme $f: M \to M'$*
$$\hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(P,f): \hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(P,M') \to \hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(P,M)$$
*is a quasi-isomorphisme too. Equivalently we says that the complexe of $R$-modules $P$ is $\pi$-projective, if for all exacte complex $M$, $\hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(P,M)$ is also exacte.*

**My question is**: Suppose $f:P \to P'$ is a quasi-isomorphism of $\pi$-projective complexes of $R$-modules. I want to show that for any complexe of $R$-module M, $\hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(f,M)$, which is at degrée $n$:
\begin{align}
\hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(f, M)_n :\hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(P', M)_n &\longmapsto \hom_{\mathcal{C}(R)}(P, M)_n\\
(\alpha_i : P'_i \to M_{i+n})_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} &\longmapsto (\alpha_i \circ f_i )_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}
\end{align}
is a quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: What is a $\pi$-projective complex?

Comment: I just made an edit, to include the definition of $\pi$-projective.

Comment: Without wanting to be impolite, where in the world did this notion come arise from? Some context might be helpful for understanding the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you call $\pi$-projective is what Spaltenstein calls $K$-projective (and this is the only term I've heard). Spaltenstein shows in his original paper that a quasi-isomorphism between $K$-projective complexes is a chain homotopy equivalence, which implies the result you want.

Comment: I don't get it, how does it implies the result ?

Comment: The functor $\mathrm{hom}(-,M)$ takes chain homotopy equivalences to chain homotopy equivalences. And chain homotopy equivalences are quasi-isomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link to the paper ?

Comment: http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1988__65_2_121_0

Comment: Spaltenstein's $K$-projective is also called $q$-projective ($q$ for "quasi-isomorphisms") and elsewhere "homotopically projective". I have not seen the $\pi$ used, though.

Comment: It's called $\pi$-projective in Avramov and Foxby's "Homological dimensions of
unbounded complexes".

Comment: In the paper by Spaltenstein, I haven't found the proof that chain homotopy equivalences are the same as quasi-isomorphismes for K-projectives complexes.

Comment: See for example Tag [070I](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/070I) (apply criterion 2 to a quasi-isomorphism $I^\bullet \to J^\bullet$ of K-injectives, and dualise for K-projectives).

Comment: (for K-injectives) Do you mean to the first argument of $\hom_{K(A)}(-,I)$ ? to get $\hom(I*,I) \to \hom(J*,I)$. The problem is, in that case $I$, $I*$, $J*$, are all K-injectives. I mean $I$ shouldn't be one, but just random complexe.